# Frozen desktop after upgrading to 14.04 from 12.10

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, mouse, screen, freeze

I've upgrades to 14.04 and during start up at login screen I got "System program problem detected" error. After logging in, the error would not go away and my desktop would be frozen, nothing opens up  yet the mouse is moving around and sometime a loading circle appears but nothing comes up. I was able to solve and error from popping up using following command:
$ sudo rm /var/crash/*

But this did not solve my freez - screen problem. I can move my mouse around the screen but I can not open folders or engage with anything on desktop.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your GUI is not active, try startx command.
If this dosn't work try to download the new Live-ISO file and Burn it to a CD or Usb-stick.
Start from that and do a reinstall, don't reformat anything - at vleast at first.
Otherwise you have a broken system - and need to get rid of the dodgy configurations, so you have to do the format.....  -- 
Do backup - if you don't allready have one, make one to a Usb-disk from your live Iso.
Happy Ubuntuing and newyear.